# Surveymonkey get_survey_details Status

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I am wondering what the status actually means in the API call get_survey_details? I was thinking that this was an active / inactive / error type status but I don't think that is the case anymore. I have closed a collector on the survey so that no response's would be gathered and I am still getting status:0. We are looking for a way of knowing from our own internal app that if a survey is active or inactive and I am not sure how to do this from the SM API. Anyone out there doing something similar or know how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"status":0 is the error code status, i.e. no error occurred in calling the API.

Surveys can't be open or closed - just collectors can.  If you call [get_collector_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_collector_list) it has a field you can request called "open", which will return a boolean on whether a collector is open or not.  You can check if any responses are being collected by requesting the list - if there are no collectors with "open":True then the survey is effectively closed.

Comment: Got it totally make sense, appreciate you showing me this!